# Content and title won't show on certain page in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I got one "front-page.php" that is a static one side page. If I use the Wordpress loop to see my latest posts at the front-page.php they all shown up.
Now I want to create a news page so I created a file "page-news.php". Removed the loop code from front-page and pasted it into page-news. Though, nothing happens.

Loop code:

```
<?php get_header();?>

<?php
if (have_posts()):
while (have_posts()): the_post();?>

<?php the_title();?>
<?php the_content();?>

<?php
endwhile;
else: echo '<p>no posts were found</p>';
endif;

 ?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

What have I missed?

Comment: I am not sure why you are opening and closing the php tags for every line, can't you open it once at the top and close it once at the bottom?

Comment: @miqdadamirali Maybe there is some other (HTML) code, which is not relevant for the question. ;)

Comment: Have you created a page called news? are you 100% this template is being run? If you just add <p>test</p> or something in the code does that show up.

Comment: I got my header/footer that is visible. Also, yes, I have created a page via Wordpress dashboard with the name "news".

Comment: Add the code I put <p>Test</p> after your get_header line - and let me know if that displays - need to make sure your template is actually getting loaded.

Comment: The paragraph is there. And on the line right below it, the name of the page "news" appear.

Comment: Good stuff - Right are you now looking to display a list of "posts" or just the content of your news page? have you typed anything in the content box for that page?

Comment: At the moment I just want to display the latest posts and header/footer. So the code sample above is all I really have right now at the "page-news.php" file. After that I will add some more structure like, only show the last six posts and a load more posts button.

Comment: In admin under settings > reading - at the top you will need to make sure "Front Page Displays" is set to a static page - your front page set as the front page and your news page set as the posts page.

Comment: I'm getting a white page throughout all the Wordpress pages after changing settings.

Comment: @SimonPollard I'm still unable to solve this. My index.php is empty. Could it perhaps be something with that?

Comment: Return it back to how it was and try using get_posts to get your news stories https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts there is a good example bit of code on that page as well. Just put the code in after <?php the_content(); ?> in your example above

Comment: @SimonPollard , nothing change. The same header, name of page and footer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add wp_Query 
the main page is consider a blog page so it have the Query default .

```
$args = array (
/*'cat'                    => $catNum,*/
'post_type'              => 'post',
'pagination'             => false,
'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
'order'                  => 'DESC',
'orderby'                => 'date',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

you should add this code before

```
if (have_posts()):
while (have_posts()): the_post();?>
```

the this part about `have_posts()` will be

```
// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
```

dont forget to add `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end so you can use many Query in one page .

Comment: I did as you instructed but I'm getting an error message: "unexpected 'endwhile'.
This is how the code looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/n63rh5t3/

Comment: I tried to create a custom page template and I added it to the "news page" in wordpress dashboard. But still, it only shows the name of the page.

Comment: about your page share the code .use this app to share the code http://climbi.com/create It will look much better